# Where has my Podcast playlist on my iPhone Gone?

Tags: ios, podcasts

Where have my podcasts gone from my playlists on my iPhone??? I used to be able to put my podcasts into a playlist in iTunes, but now they don't seem to go onto a playlist and can only be played via the Podcast app. This is terrible as you can't organize or loop  podcasts, and is dangerous whilst driving as you have to look at the phone after every episode is finished.

Is there a way to organize my podcasts?

Answer (score 2):

Delete the Podcasts app, and you'll be able to play them through the Music app again. Some people have had to reboot their devices to get them to show in Music; turn the iPhone off then on again.

Comment: I can see my podcast playlist in the Music app, but even after rebooting it displays, "There's no music in this playlist." In iTunes on my PC I can see podcasts in this playlist in the "On My Device" section. Using iOS 11.2.2. My new iPhone is a distant second to my old iPod Nano for playing podcasts, and I'd keep using it if it only supported Bluetooth playback.

Answer (score 0):

Compromise workaround (with issues): Switch 'media kind' from 'podcast' to 'music'.

This allows you to play podcast playlists from the Music app on your iOS device, but it makes for the following issues in iTunes on your computer:

- Podcasts *may* disappear from the Podcasts library and show up in the Music library, but not always. Some will show up in both places.
- The "Download" option in the right-click menu no longer appears and although the cloud/download icon still shows up it is not functional. These will work as expected if you switch back to 'podcast'.
- It becomes difficult to easily tell what media kind a podcast is. If you right-click on a podcast, those converted to 'music' will show "Song Info" instead of "Get Info." View>Show View Options lets you add a file kind column, but this is different than 'media kind'.
- If you select multiple podcasts with mixed 'media kind' you will not be able to use Get Info to edit the details. When you try you'll see this message

  - Your selection contains more than one kind of media. All items must be the same kind in order to view or edit them together.

Recommended workflow:

1. Download the podcasts in iTunes
2. Put the new podcasts in a temporary playlist (to ensure you don't have mixed 'media kind' attributes)
3. Switch to the playlist, select all the podcasts, right-click, Get Info, Options tab, change 'media kind' to 'Music'
4. Move podcasts to your podcast playlist
5. Connect your iOS device to iTunes, click on it in the upper left, under "Settings" in the left pane click Music, make sure that either

   - "Entire music library" is selected in the "Sync Music" section, or
   - Click the checkbox next to your podcast playlists in the "Playlists" section
6. Sync the iOS device
7. On the iOS device open the Music app, tap Library in the lower left corner, choose Playlists, play

The workarounds mentioned in [Podcast playlist not syncing](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4329334) no longer work for me.

Notes

- I'm using iTunes 12.7 on Windows and iOS 11.2.2.
- This leaves the 'genre' as Podcast so they will remain grouped in the Music library.