# Podcast-containing playlists on modern iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, podcasts, playlist

I have used iTunes to create various Smart Playlists that contain podcasts using intelligent criteria (unplayed and most recently added podcasts;  least recently played music + 3 hours of unplayed podcasts, etc.)

I am able to transfer these playlists to a 3rd generation iPod Touch running iOS 6.1, or a brand new Nano, and get the listening experience I expect.

When I sync the playlist to an iPhone 6, it creates an empty playlist on the device (if it were only podcasts), but the requisite podcasts show up in the Podcasts app.   I had a similar problem with the iPod Touch years ago, but I was able to delete the Podcasts app.  It looks as though this deletion is not possible on the iPhone.

**Q: Can someone show me how to get a playlist containing podcasts to show up on a phone?**  TIA

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to view podcasts through Music.app.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this. Although I don't have a iPhone 6, I think your problem is that you have iCloud Music Library turned on. Try turning iCloud music library off on your phone. Compile your smart playlists in iTunes and make sure "Sync podcasts" is checked and also check the smart playlists that you want to sync under "podcasts". Those smart playlists will show up in the podcasts app as a podcast station that contains all of your smart playlists. They won't, however, show up in the music app. That boat has sailed.

This has been working for me with the new iOS versions. What's not working is now that I want to try Apple Music and I turn iCloud Music Library my smart playlist station in the podcast app disappears!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, you have to make sure you do not have media kind set to anything in you search query. At least that's what finally got them to display on my 6 Plus with iOS 9.2 using iTunes v12.3.2.35 (64 Bit)

Comment: I found this works but there are some issues. See my answer in [Where has my Podcast playlist on my iPhone Gone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312106/73959) for details.